# Document locked by SharePoint

Tags: office-web-apps, file

I am trying to read values from document after that the file was edited in Office Web Apps. Problem is, that this document is locked by Sharepoint (SPFile.LockType - Shared). I tried to Check Out and Check In the file and read it afterward, but this "solution" isn't reliable. Sometimes document doesn't contains new values. I think it is related with this issue
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899709/en

Comment: More information would be helpful...

Comment: I made webpart which provides url to xlviewer (eg. http://localhost/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=/Documents/copy_template.xlsx&Source=/Pages/CustomPage.aspx). Before this url is hit the file is checked out. After the file was edited it is automatically checked in. At last I'm trying to open it and read data with OpenXML. That is all.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also could be due to another person opening the document.  Verify that the check out requirement is not enabled on your library.  This will prevent multiple users from opening and modifying a document.

Comment: Without checking in/out it takes more time to get updated document. After the document is checked in, I'm trying to open it programmatically and parse it.